# Meaning of 重剑 aside from the fencing sword epee

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The main translation of 重剑 is epee, which is a fencing sword. However, in a novel, I saw the term used in a fighting scene. It was also described to be placed on the character's back. Since the two words separately are heavy and sword, is it possible that the author meant it to be a broadsword or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it means **heavy sword**. In this case, we should comprehend it separately. So 重剑 can mean *a very heavy sword*. It's not that epee in sports.